# Pandoc-mode ignoring settings file?

Tags: emacs, pandoc

I'm trying to set pandoc-mode on Emacs to use `xelatex` as the default LaTeX engine.  From my understanding of [the documentation](https://joostkremers.github.io/pandoc-mode/), I should be able to do this by:

- Opening the Pandoc menu and setting the LaTeX engine to `xelatex`, e.g. `C-c / o s T e`.
- Saving these as global settings with `C-c / s g`.

This creates a `native.pandoc` file in the `pandoc-data-dir` as expected and if I open up the file, then I do see `(latex-engine . "xelatex")` in the file.

My problem is that when I try to convert any Markdown file to a PDF with `C-c / p`, the standard pdfLaTeX engine is used.  In fact, even within the same session, the latex-engine option seems to be ignored.

Any idea what's going on here?  (PS xelatex is installed on my system and available from the command line.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have thought of this.

The problem was that `C-c / p` first converts the file to LaTeX and then to PDF, and so the settings file needs to be called `latex.pandoc` in order to work.  I also changed the output format in the file from `native` to `(write . "latex")`.